# Parquet File from Data Lakes to SQL Pool - Arithmetic overflow converting tinyint to TINYINT

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-synapse, azure-synapse-analytics

We're trying to import a parquet File from Data Lakes to the Azure dedicated SQL Pool but getting an error randomly.

The error is:

HadoopSqlException: Arithmetic overflow error converting tinyint to data type TINYINT

In Synapse Studio, it's a simple copy task with the source as the parquet file and the sink as the SQL Pool table. We have several TINYINT columns. In the Parquet file, it is represented as INT32 BUT all of the values fit in TINYINT. So why is this error happening?

Comment: How you are transferring data via code or using pipeline?

Comment: Using a pipeline.

Comment: can you add screenshots? what you are doing and error image?

Comment: If I enable staging in the Copy Data task, it works. Why do I need to enable staging....it's already in Data Lakes. I don't want it to go from Data Lakes to Data Lakes to SQL Pool which is a waste of time.

Comment: Since it's hard to know which tinyint column the error refers, you can try to insert into new table (using the pipeline auto create table feature), and then run select on the tinyint columns to find the value that's causing the error.

Comment: @ChenHirsh Thanks, I just tried that and it worked in auto creating a new table. The differences in fields are: Field1 (smallint, int), Field2 (varchar(10), nvarchar(max)), field3 (tinyint, int), valuedate (datetime, datetime2(7)). I checked the TINYINT values, they are all equal to or below 255. Do you know what else to try?

Comment: @ChenHirsh If I exclude the TINYINT columns, the import works perfectly. The thing is, all of the values in the TINYINT columns are less than 255....so why is it giving arithmetic overflow if I include it?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the same error.

[image]

You're presumably attempting to enter data into a table when its 'tinyint' column has hit its data type's maximum if you receive the error message, "***Arithmetic overflow error converting tinyint to data type TINYINT***."

- In this instance, the `tinyint` data type, **which has a range of 0 to 255** and has numbers above this maximum in your file, is used by my `tinyint` column.
- In data column mapping of file, it is taking as `int32`  even it has values greater than 255

To resolve this convert column datatype of column to `bigint` or `int` using **pre-copy script**.

```sql
ALTER TABLE table_name
ALTER COLUMN column_name INT;
```

[image]

Now the pipeline is running successfully.

[image]

Comment: I found the issue. Apparently, Parquet Files in DataLakes or Synapse supports only 0-127 range and NOT 0-255 range. When the value is in 0-127 range, it works. When it is in 0-255 range, it fails with the arithmetic overflow error. Can you confirm if this is a bug?

Comment: I reproduced with value 200 in parquet file and it's working fine for me.

Comment: Strange, it is not working when it's beyond 127. I tested it multiple times. Even created a sample table and pipeline and tried it, same error if it's beyond 0-127.